# The time is displayed every 5ms, and the difference between displaying "fff" is not 5, it How is it calculated?

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

I want to display the time every 5ms, and 'fff' is used in wpf to represent `ms`.

Why is the `fff` difference in the code of `new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 5);` displayed result not `5`? How is it calculated?

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
        <ListBox Height="140" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,31,0,0" 
                 Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="308" />
        <Button x:Name="btn" Click="btn_Click" Height="50" Content=" stop"/>
    </Grid>
```

Codebehind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Threading;
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
         DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        public bool What { get; set; }
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Start");

            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 5);
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);

            timer.Start();
        }
        private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ":" +
                DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + ":"+DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString());

            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
            listBox1.Items.MoveCurrentToLast();
            listBox1.SelectedItem = listBox1.Items.CurrentItem;
            listBox1.ScrollIntoView(listBox1.Items.CurrentItem);
        }

        private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }
       
    }
}
```

The result:

[image: 3]

**Update :**

```
  public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
           Task timerTask = RunPeriodically(sendRequest, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(num), tokenSource.Token);
            
        }
        private void sendRequest()
        {
            k++;
            datas.Add(DateTime.Now );
       
        }
        async Task RunPeriodically(Action action, TimeSpan interval, CancellationToken token)
        {
            while (k<7)
            {
                action();
                await Task.Delay(interval, token);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. A DispatcherTimer does not run with an exact interval of 5 ms.

Comment: Relevant remark from the documentation "Timers are not guaranteed to execute exactly when the time interval occurs, but they are guaranteed to not execute before the time interval occurs."

Comment: Why do you want a 5ms interval in the first place? It matters. Animations don't use timers for example. A busy UI thread would result in delayed and jerky animations for example. WPF itself offers  [transition animation support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/animation-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) out of the box

Comment: The default timers used by any OS (Linux, Mac, Windows) *don't* have high resolution or good skew because they aren't meant for audio/video applications. High CPU usage can delay timer event handlers in all applications. To get smooth multimedia (video, audio, animation) OSs offer special real-time or multimedia timer types that are guaranteed to either fire at specific intervals or not at all. It's better to lose a frame than delay it. Most of the time applications don't use these directly, they tell the OS to play audio or draw animations.

Comment: 200 a second. The ui might not even get to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the Interval of the timer to 5 milliseconds, the timer will not be executed every 5 milliseconds. The timer doesn't have that high resolution.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.interval):

> Timers are not guaranteed to execute exactly when the time interval
> occurs, but they are guaranteed to not execute before the time
> interval occurs. This is because DispatcherTimer operations are placed
> on the Dispatcher queue like other operations. When the
> DispatcherTimer operation executes is dependent on the other jobs in
> the queue and their priorities.

---

`Task.Delay` also uses a timer internally. The resolution is again not high enough for 5ms intervals.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay):

> This method depends on the system clock. This means that the time
> delay will approximately equal the resolution of the system clock if
> the millisecondsDelay argument is less than the resolution of the
> system clock, which is approximately 15 milliseconds on Windows
> systems.

Comment: Please see the update part in my question, it is also not possible to display the update time every 5ms in Task. Are the reasons the same?

Comment: @wpf what is the actual problem you want to solve? People don't want to see a listbox with 20 time values per second. What are you trying to use the timer for?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out that fff is not updating correctly for the 5ms of the code. The example in the question above is just for testing.

Comment: `Task.Delay` also uses a timer internally. As you can see here: https://source.dot.net/System.Private.CoreLib/A.html#3d5ce2143a41d705

Comment: @wpf no, that's what you assume is relevant. It's not. Users don't care about adding list items every 5ms. Why do you want a 5ms timer?

Comment: `Task.Delay` uses a thread timer so isn't affected by a blocked UI thread BUT it still doesn't have 5ms resolution nor does it have any skew guarantees. Only special multimedia or real-time timers do.